# how to edit the partition table of a system when you clone it onto another drive that does not have the same partition table?

Tags: linux, rhel, rsync

Ok so I used rsync command to clone a system onto my server. I next mounted a drive onto a running system so that I could tamper with the target system.(so for clarification the target is not running) just a mounted drive. I then rsynced my clone from the server to the root location on the drive. - Here is my issue when booting the target system now, if fails as it is looking for the former partitions of the cloned system which do not exist on this drive as it is much smaller. So I have some questions:

1. where is the partition table or MBR in rhel 7 and can I change it at will to just use the current partition it is on since the new drive has one partition?
2. it dumped me into emergency mode could I possible just rebuild the initramfs in order for it to sort out the partitions ?
3. Is the partition pointing apart of the grub config script? below is the command I used to generate the clone to target

```
rsync -av -e ssh --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* <server-ip>:/path/to/image/root/ /path/to/target/clone/root/
```

the target did enter boot but it failed during start up.
I found where in grub.cfg file the original --set=root points to the old hard drive. can I just edit this file to say the new drive or is there a way to regenerate the grub.cfg for the new drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync is not suitable for this use case better to use it when trying to backup **DATA** filesystems rather than  the **SYSTEM** itself.

You can use **dd** command instead :

Stop the hosted applications and services.

Copy the whole disk using dd and zip it.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c > <path>/backup_image.gz
```

Execute a **checksum** on the zip.

Unzip the backup.

Boot your target system with a **live CD** Installation.

Transfer the zip and the checksum file
using **rsync** or **scp** .

Execute a checksum on the recevied zip and compare both checksums.

Unzip and copy the backup drive to the new one :

```
gunzip -c <path_to_diskX>.gz | dd of=/dev/diskY
```

**About your last comment :**

**dd** perform a bit to bit copy.
Since your targeted drive is smaller than the source and your are using **MBR** which resides in the first sector. You have to do an additional steps to do so.

*On the source drive :*

Turn off **swap** space.

Resize & shrink your **filesystems** to the used space only ( + some Mbs ).

Shrink partitions with **gparted** or another utility ( the size should be

*On the target drive :*

Check the partition with **gparted**.

Run **fsck** on your filesystems.

Comment: I thought about using dd at first however the target drive is significantly smaller than the original host system- development system was done on a normal 1TB drive but the embedded system has a 32Gig compact flash. I used rsync so I would only copy actual content instead of unused space. As I understood it dd will copy bit for bit correct? That bit for bit was my main reasoning for not using the dd command

Comment: I have made an edit :)